# Transition between two images

Tags: actionscript-3, blackberry-playbook

I'm developing an ActionScript 3.0 app for Blackberry Playbook.

I'm using [Loader Class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Loader.html) to show an image.

I want to show another image, at the same place, when the user clicks on this image.

How can I do that? I would like to make a transition between these two images. The second image will go from 0 alpha to 100 alpha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the transition you want to do. For the simplest alpha, you can go through a Tweener engine like irot suggested, or you can do something simple yourself.

**Simple**:
Basically, when you click on the image, load in the next one (or have it already loaded). Start an enterframe listener to load it up. Something like:

```
// we're assuming that "image2" is the second image and it has an alpha
// of 0.0 and visible of false. "image1" is the first image and currently 
// on stage

// the on click handler for the image
private function _onImageClick( e:MouseEvent ):void
{
    // add a enter frame to the stage - I'm going to assume you
    // have access through this.stage
    this.stage.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, this._onEnterFrame );

    // make our second image visible so we can fade it up
    this.image2.visible = true;
}

// called every frame
private function _onEnterFrame( e:Event ):void
{
    // image2 is the second image
    this.image2.alpha += 0.05; // slow fade

    if( this.image2.alpha >= 1.0 )
    {
        this.image2.alpha = 1.0;

        // hide the first image
        this.image1.alpha = 0.0;
        this.image1.visible = false;

        // remove the enter frame event listener
        this.stage.removeEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, this._onEnterFrame );
    }
}
```

**Bit more complicated**: Check out the BitmapData class and it's `merge()` or `pixelDisolve()` functions: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with any Tween engines? I would recommend [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/) if you are not.

What I would usually do is load all the images I plan to use and then stack two or more of them where I want them. Only one of these images will be visible at any time (alpha = 1).

On your click handler, you can do one of two things:

- Tween the visible image's alpha down to 0, then have an onComplete handler tween your next image's alpha up to 1
- Alternatively, you could just have two tweens running at once. One would tween the visible image's alpha down to 0, the other tweening the next image's alpha up to 1

irot

Comment: Another alternative is to place an image over another image and set alpha from image one to 0.